# Python determine screenreader is enabled

Tags: python, screen-readers

I'm running a Python program with an interactive terminal output/input menu.
However, it doesn't quite work for screenreaders at the moment (it's using `termios`).

Is there a way to determine if a screenreader is enabled/running on a Linux based system via python?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. More than that, Apple once tried to add such a capability, but it was considered as discriminatory as it would lead to interface differences between "accessible" and "normal" versions. I agree with this point of view, because I saw quite a bunch of websites having "special" versions for visually impaired which, of course, lacked much of the functionality of "normal" versions.

So, your (and everyone's) solution is to build accessible interfaces, regardless of the fact whether your user *is using* a screen reader at the moment or not.